# Use of Cultures in Gentics Mesh

Tags: gentics-mesh

Is it possible to use cultures for languages in gentics-mesh.
I just found languages in the config files, like de, en.

Is it also possible to use a culture like `de_De`, `de_CH` and then have `de` as first fallback and `en` as second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is currently not possible but we plan to support this in the future. I created an issue: https://github.com/gentics/mesh/issues/392